# Moving and Rotating an image simultaneously with AffineTransform

Tags: java

I am coding a simple shooter game whereby i want to rotate my character to the direction of the mouse and "fire". I have done all the code for this except rotating the actual image. Here is some of my code so far: (THIS IS ALL UNDER THE PAINT COMPONENT METHOD)

```
   xCent = x + 50;
    yCent = y + 50; // x and y center of image ( x and y change depending on Keyboard Input)       
    a.setToRotation(theta, xCent,yCent); // a = new AffineTransform()    Here is my calculation of theta (under the MouseMotionListener):  theta = Math.atan2(e.getY() - yCent,e.getX() - xCent);
    a.setToTranslation(x,y);
    a.setToRotation(theta, xCent,yCent);
    g2.drawImage(charac,a, null);
```

How do i go about now "setting" the x and y coordinates of the image for the Graphics2D object to draw it??

Comment: Sorry, ignore the last  a.setToRotation(theta, xCent,yCent);

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19387.html

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {`

    AffineTransform transformer = new AffineTransform();
    transformer.translate(5,5);
    transformer.scale(2,2);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.setTransform(transformer);
    // draw to g2d.
}
```

In your case off course you would do the rotation and then translation rather than translate and scale.

Comment: I have tried this, but the translate(x,y) seems to override the rotate(theta)